# Not an editor command: TmuxNavigateLeft

Tags: tmux, neovim

## error

- on first open, I get this error
- after running `:PlugInstall`, everything works as expected

  - It's not reinstalling the plugin each time `- vim-tmux-navigator: Already installed`

## environment

- NVIM v0.5.0-dev+1267-g7bf62ab02
- tmux 3.2

Answer (score 0):

moving `Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'` from `local_init.vim` to `init.vim` solved this.

I guess `local_init.vim` isn't sourced on first open?

Here're the relevant lines in `init.vim`

```
"" Include user's local vim config
if filereadable(expand("~/.config/nvim/local_init.vim"))
  source ~/.config/nvim/local_init.vim
endif
```